# React Js - Problema al agregar elementos de forma dinámica a un array mediante un input

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs

Estoy agregando elementos (números) de forma dinámica a una array, mediante un input; el problema es el siguiente, al momento de establecer el primero, no se agrega, posteriormente al ingresar el segundo número, se agrega el primero; es decir, al establecer el primer número el array se imprime vacío y al agregar otro elemente e imprimir, se indica el primer elemento; tengo lo siguiente:

```
 const FormPricesUsed = () => {

  const [pricesUsed, setPricesUsed] = useState([]);
  const [prices, setPrices] = useState();

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      setPricesUsed([...pricesUsed, Number(prices)])
      setPrices('')
      console.log(pricesUsed)
  }

  const handleChange = (e) => {
      switch (e.target.name) {
          case 'prices':
              setPrices(e.target.value)         
          break;
          default:
              break;
      }
  }

  return (
      <Container>
          <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <input 
                  type="number"
                  name="prices"
                  value={prices}
                  onChange={handleChange}
              /> 
          </Form>
      </Container>
  );
}
export default FormPricesUsed;
```

Comment: Coloca el `console.log(pricesUsed)` antes del `return`, en el block scope `FormPricesUsed ` y se observará el valor deseado, recordemos que los hooks son asincrónicos, los cambios de estado solo se pueden ver despues de devolver el componente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pesar de que se imprima vacío, en realidad sí se está agregando, estás tratando con un asunto de asincronismo propio de los componentes de React, entonces estás mostrando en consola antes de que termine de agregarse el número al array.
para poder verlo reflejado en el momento, utiliza useEffect(), este se ejecuta cada vez que alguno de los estados cambia y te permitirá ver los datos al momento.

Prueba utilizándolo de esta manera:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(pricesUsed);
    console.log(prices);
}, [pricesUsed,prices]) //Aquí van los estados que estará leyendo useEffect esperando por el cambio.
```

Para poder usar useEffect, no te olvides de importar.

import React, {useEffect} from 'react';